# When will compiler generate default constructor for a derived class

Tags: c++

Here is my observation:

The compiler will NOT generate a default constructor for a derived class whose base class has defined a constructor.

```
// example
class ClassCBase
{
public:
    ClassCBase(int i) {}
};

class ClassC : public ClassCBase
{

};

int main()
{
  ClassC c; // error C2512: 'ClassC' : 
                // no appropriate default constructor available
}
```

Q1> Do I understand correctly?

Q2> Are there any other cases that the compiler will not generated the default constructors for a derived class?

Comment: Perhaps these error messages describe the situation better: http://ideone.com/Fy8uw

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler won't generate a default constructor if the superclass has no default constructor. In other words, since the superclass constructor needs an argument, and the compiler can't be expected to know what an appropriate default value is, the compiler will fail to generate a useful default constructor. But if you added a no-argument constructor to  `ClassCBase`, `ClassC` would be usable as-is.

Comment: It will generate one (as long as there are no other constructors) but the generation of the constructor will cause a compile time error as it requires the superclass to have a no argument constructor.

Comment: Whether the compiler declares/defines a default constructor has little value. The Standard says that the program is ill-formed, and it's up to each compiler to choose how to report the error.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler will not *define an implicit default constructor* (not just "declare", the definition is the key here) for the derived class if there is no default constructor for the base class. (Any constructor that can be called with no arguments is a default constructor, no matter the actual signature, as long as default arguments are provided.)

So we can summarize the requirements for *any* class to have a well-formed implicitly defined constructor:

- No const members.
- No reference members.
- All base classes must have accessible default constructors.
- All non-static members must have accessible default constructors.

Comment: Arguably, the compiler will define a default construtor for the derived class if it is used, but because the constructor that it is required to generate is ill-formed, the program is ill-formed.

Comment: @Charles: Indeed, I added "well-formed" to the text.

Comment: Thinking about the first paragraph, perhaps "The compiler will not be able to define..." better describes the cause/effect. I'm not sure.

Comment: @Charles: Well, given what you just said, the compiler *will* define the equivalent of `Foo::Foo() : {}`. It's just that the actual construction process cannot take place. Is this 2003/12.1.7? It's a bit opaque...

Comment: Hm, somehow 12.1.6 in the FDIS is a tiny bit clearer. Also whoops, I forgot about members! :-)

Comment: @Kerrek: *no const members* --> I think this only applies for the generation of the assignement operator, and then only if one has not overloaded the assignement operator of the type of the member to be a `const` method (insane, but possible I think).

Comment: @Mattieu: I believe you *must* initialize const members in any event.